# How to use Manipulate in filter design to plot the sum two raised-cosines?

Tags: function-construction, manipulate

I would like to be able to add a raised cosine to a "standard" raised cosine. With a time delay which I could manipulate (so the shape of the standard cosine function is altered, meaning the function becomes like the image below or a reversed example of this. (But above y=0)[image]). I do however have one limitation and that is that after a period of 0.3 seconds it should be just a baseline.

The standard cosine is:`0.05 + Piecewise[{{3.95 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t, 1]/0.3])/2, 
    Mod[t, 1] < 0.3}}]`

I've tried a Module but seem to get stuck

```
    Manipulatedelastance[t0_, t1_, tdelay_, period_] := Module[{},

  Originalfunc = 
   0.05 + Piecewise[{{3.95 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t, 1]/0.3])/2, 
       Mod[t, 1] < 0.3}}];
  ToBeAddedfunction = 3.95 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t - tdelay, 1]/period])/2;
  Combinedfunction = 
   0.05 + Piecewise[{{(((3.95)*(1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t, 1]/period])/2) + 
          EVLtr2)/2, Mod[t, 1] < 0.3}}];



  EATtr = 
   0.17 + Piecewise[{{0.73 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t - 0.9, 1]/0.1])/2, 
       Mod[t, 1] > 0.9}}];
  EPATtr = 
   0.2 + Piecewise[{{0.5 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t - 0.9, 1]/0.1])/2, 
       Mod[t, 1] > 0.9}}];
  EPVLtr = 
   0.08 + Piecewise[{{3.95/5 (1 - Cos[(2 Pi Mod[t, 1]/0.3)])/2, 
       Mod[t, 1] < 0.3}}];



  {Plot[Originalfunc, {t, t0, t1}], 
   Plot[{Originalfunc, ToBeAddedfunction, Combinedfunction}, {t, t0, 
     t1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Originalfunc", "ToBeAddedfunction", 
      "Combinedfunction"}], 
   Plot[{Originalfunc, EATtr, EPATtr, EPVLtr, Combinedfunction}, {t, 
     t0, t1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {"EVL", "EAT", "EPAT", "EPVL", "Enew"}]}]

Manipulate[
 Manipulatedelastance[t0, t1, tdelay, period], {{t0, 0}, 0, 
  30}, {{t1, 2}, 0, 20}, {{tdelay, 0.7}, 0, 1}, {{period, 0.3}, 0, 1}]
```

I know this is probably not the best explanation of all but I would really appreciated if somebody could help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are wanting to do, then try something like this,

```
OriginalFn[t_] := 0.05 + 3.95 Piecewise[{{1/2 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t, 1]/0.3]), Mod[t, 1] < 0.3}}]

ToBeAddedFn[t_, delay_, period_, amplitude_] := amplitude *
  Piecewise[{
    {1/2 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Mod[t - delay, 1]/period]), Mod[t - delay, 1] < period}
  }]

Manipulate[
  Row[{
    Plot[{OriginalFn[t], ToBeAddedFn[t, delay, period, amplitude]}, {t, 0, 0.4}, PlotRange -> {0.0, 4}, ImageSize -> 300],
    Plot[1/2 (OriginalFn[t] + ToBeAddedFn[t, delay, period, amplitude]), {t, 0, 0.4}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
  }],
  {{period, 0.2}, 0.015, 0.3}, 
  {{delay, 0.003}, 0, 0.3 - period}, 
  {{amplitude, 1.97}, 0, 8}]
```

The above code generates the following,

[image: output from manipulate]